# Angular JS Prevent Content to load when app.run is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `AngularJS v1.2.23`.

I want to execute `app.run` function before controller or any function load.

but the content is load before `app.run` function completes its execution.

I tried so far :

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$location,$auth,$cookieStore){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Run Function!!!");
    },5000);
});
```

but when i call a app then a controller is load first and then i get a log message.
any suggestions?

Comment: how you load content? are you load it in run func or in controllers?

Comment: i load it with Controller

Comment: App stage gets called after the config stage, but you cannot control the order of controller or app.run execution. You may have to look at `$routeProvider` `resolve` property if it can help.

Comment: It just like i want to give loader before a page load.

Comment: can you provide fiddle with what you have and what you want?